# pandas default aggregation function for rest of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I'd need to groupby and aggregate dataframe.

Some columns have specific aggregation function, for the rest I'd like to use `first`.

I just don't want to hardcode the rest of column names, because it can differ by case. Do you have any elegant idea how to achieve that?

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1,2,3,4,5],
                   "col2": ["aa","aa","bb","bb","cc"],
                   "col3": ["b","b","b","b","b"],
                   "col4": ["c","c","c","c","c"],
                   "col5": [11,12,13,14,15]}
                  )

df.groupby(["col2"]).agg({
                          "col1": "mean",
                          "col5": "max",
                          "col3": "first",
                          "col4": "first"
                          })
```

output:

```
      col1  col5 col3 col4
col2
aa     1.5    12    b    c
bb     3.5    14    b    c
cc     5.0    15    b    c
```

but I don't want to explicitly specify

```
                          "col3": "first",
                          "col4": "first"
```

Simply all the columns not used in `groupby` and `agg` should be aggregated with default function.

Comment: See the duplicate for a method to set a default function using a dictionary. In your case you can use `d = {c: 'first' for c in df.columns} ; d['col1'] = 'mean' ; d['col5'] = 'max' ; df.groupby(["col2"]).agg(d)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create dictionary dynamic - first define non `first` aggregations and then for all columns without column used for `groupby` and keys from `d`:

```
d = {"col1": "mean", "col5": "max"}

agg = {**d, **dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['col2'] + list(d.keys())), 'first')}
print (agg)
{'col1': 'mean', 'col5': 'max', 'col3': 'first', 'col4': 'first'}
```

Or create dictionary by all values without groupby column(s) and set different aggregations:

```
agg = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['col2']), 'first')
agg['col1'] = 'mean'
agg['col5'] = 'max'
print (agg)
{'col1': 'mean', 'col3': 'first', 'col4': 'first', 'col5': 'max'}
```

---

```
df = df.groupby(["col2"]).agg(agg)
print (df)
      col1  col5 col3 col4
col2                      
aa     1.5    12    b    c
bb     3.5    14    b    c
cc     5.0    15    b    c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a dictionary with a default function and customize the specific column:

```
d = {c: 'first' for c in df.columns}
d['col1'] = 'mean'
d['col5'] = 'max'
# or 
d = {c: 'first' for c in df.columns}
d.update({'col1': 'mean', 'col5': max})

del d['col2'] # if you don't want col2 as column

out = df.groupby(["col2"]).agg(d)
```

output:

```
      col1 col3 col4  col5
col2                           
aa     1.5    b    c    12
bb     3.5    b    c    14
cc     5.0    b    c    15
```